# I've built a bitcoin miner and mined. Now what I do?

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools, hash

I've mined **bitcoin** to test and understand cryptocurrency better. Which generated this hash `00000431fb66ed96815b3829e975c2235a64b9a646c0bd1cc526dc1727c1f16b`**(nonce value of 300712)** What I do with this now? Do I go to blockchain and submit it? How can I do that? Can someone explain me? I'm very new to cryptocurrency and I'd like to learn more about it.

Comment: That looks like a low difficulty. What chain did you mine?

Comment: Yeah it was to test. It's lvl 5 difficulty which is mined by python 3.9

Comment: To extend the blockchain, you have to mine a block at the current difficulty. The current difficulty is 20,082,460,130,830, so just a tad more than 5. You should check out https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/148/5406, and https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406.

Comment: How do you view the current difficulty and how can you even get the reward when you mine that? I have some many questions

Comment: Block headers commit to the previous block hash and the difficulty, so you literally cannot begin mining without knowing this. Typically you'd get this information from a full node; for example using the `getblocktemplate` RPC call of Bitcoin Core.

Answer (score 1):

> **generated this hash [...]. What I do with this now?**

I'm pretty sure the things you should do include:

- Check that the prior block referenced by your block template is still at the head of the chain.
- Ensure your block will pass all the consensus validation rules.
- Identify a handful of peer nodes using Bitcoin's peer discovery process/protocol
- Send a Bitcoin message to those peers stating that you have a new block
- Listen for incoming requests for that block and respond to them
- Wait for another 100 blocks to be added to the chain that has your block in it.
- Spend your block reward or continue to retain it

See also

- [What exactly is Mining?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/148/13866)
- [Whats the process of Creating a Block on the BlockChain](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/7330/13866)

---

> **How do you view the current difficulty**

By viewing the difficulty value in a few recent blocks and if the difficulty interval is here, by applying the difficulty recalculation algorithm.

- [How is difficulty calculated?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/5838/13866)

---

> **and how can you even get the reward when you mine that?**

The reward is in the coinbase transaction you added to your block template before hashing. You can spend it 100 blocks later (see above)

- [How do mining rewards get verified?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/102338/13866)